# Default values for ProducerConfigs in Spring-Boot Apache Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an Spring Boot project up and running with Kafka being implemented .

I configured a Producer and sent an message with topic "Demo" .
But i didn't set any of the properties like
**bootstrap.servers** = [localhost:9092]
**value.serializer** = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
which we normally set while running kafka project-Producer
My Project ran succesfully and i was able to consume the message

My question was how does Spring-Boot know of these ProducerConfig properties ?? Are there any default values

Also i saw in logs

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id = 
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = null
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 0
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Where are these properties being set ?

Answer (score 3):

See the [Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Scroll down to Kafka and click the [link to KafkaProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java).

Answer (score 2):

Look at [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java). 
There you can find that some of the properties have default values

```
define(BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Type.INT, 16384, atLeast(0), Importance.MEDIUM, BATCH_SIZE_DOC)
```

Comment: Yes i saw ProducerConfig class but didnt find anything like  bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]

Comment: This table shows default values as well: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs. The Spring Boot knows nothing about that `ProducerConfig` and what you see in the logs comes from the Kafka Client, not Boot.

Comment: Boot applies some defaults (serializers/deserializers, bootstrap servers)l See my answer for links.

Comment: @ArtemBilan i did not find default value of bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092 in ProducerConfig class

Comment: Right. This one comes from Spring Boot. indeed. See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaProperties.java

Comment: @ArtemBilan The github example that you shared contains bootstrap.servers manually configured as localhost:9092 , but in my project i havent set property anywhere , so from where Spring Boot know that it should listen on port 9092 for kafka

Comment: Correct, because that is a default value in Spring Boot